# Will firebase and googlemaps work in huawei-mate 30

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

**What is the scenario:**

1. I have an application that is installed on an android device
2. It is using `GoogleMaps` & `Firebase`

**Question:**

Will `GoogleMaps` and `Firebase` used in the application work on future Huawei devices? Since `Play Store` nor `GoogleServices` are available?

Comment: without google services, map doesn't work

Comment: No, but **Huawei** will properly develop replacements for those services

Comment: Correct, Maps Kit and Location Kit - https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/ - scoll down the page to the footer section.

Answer (score 2):

No, Your application will only work on Huawei phones having GMS. If you want to make them work on HMS (Huawei non GMS) devices You will have to integrate the relevant kits of HMS.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase and Google Maps cannot run on Mate 30, because Google does not allow GMS installation on Huawei phones. That is, Google capabilities provided via GMS are not available on Huawei phones with HMS.

You can use capabilities provided by [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect) and [HMS Core](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms) instead. These capabilities are now mature and some of them can [run on non-Huawei phones](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/emui-version-dependent-0000001050042515-V5). You can also use [HMS Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/) to quickly integrate HMS capabilities.